# Reading regular expression from a file

Tags: java, regex

I am making use of dk.brics.automaton tool. I am using a file in which I have regular expressions . I want to compute DFA states of all those  regular expressions. eg I have this RE `"/^\x3c(REQIMG|RVWCFG)\x3e/ism"`  which I take it in string array retval[0]. The code works great but the problem is when I am not using any file for reading and just pass this above RE in the function RegExp then it says invalid escape.So, when I write the RE as
`"/^\\x3c(REQIMG|RVWCFG)\\x3e/ism"` then it doesn't give me error.

I am not getting it why am I not getting this invalid escape when I am reading RE from file

```
      String line = null;
      String retval[];
        int j=0;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader =new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            retval= line.split("\t");
            int i=0;

            for(i=0;i<retval.length;i++){
                    try{ 
                        j=j+1;
                    RegExp r = new RegExp(retval[i],ALL);
                    Automaton a = r.toAutomaton();
                    System.out.println("RE : "+retval[i]);

                    System.out.println("States"+a.getNumberOfStates()); 

                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                    }

            }   

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

In Java, the backslash `\` inside a literal string denotes an escape sequence. Hence it has special meaning to the compiler. That is why, in order to tell the compiler that you need backslash to mean an actual backslash (and not an "escape sequencer"), you need to escape it explicitly again with another backslash.

***Why the error in the literal string?***
In your example, when the compiler encounters `..\x...` it treats the first occurrence of backslash `\` as an escape sequencer but then finds `x` which does not form a [valid escape sequence.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) Hence the error. That's why you have to escape the `\` when used in literal strings like this: `\\x`: `"/^\\x3c(REQIMG|RVWCFG)\\x3e/ism"`

***Why no error when reading from file?***
However, while reading from a file, you are not dealing with literals, hence the string  stored in the variable does not need any "escape"ing as the compiler can easily figure that all data in the file is to be treated as verbatim strings. Hence you do not have to escape backslashes here and keep the regex as it is meant to be: `/^\x3c(REQIMG|RVWCFG)\x3e/ism`

***Side Note:***
Unfortunately Java does not have [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx) (yet) like .NET has. For example, in .NET, you could make the string verbatim like below and [also this](http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/string.html).

```
RegExp(@"/^\x3c(REQIMG|RVWCFG)\x3e/ism",...)
```

Comment: But if my regular expression means /s ie white space then what to do?

Comment: Please do check this document as well, as it is related to the tool which I am using http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/index.html

Comment: @Zara I believe you mean `\s`. In that case, escape the backslash again: `\\s`, like you do for `\x` as `\\x`.

Comment: @Zara The tool is a Java library which does not change the semantics of how to write literal strings. You still have to escape backslashes.

Comment: Do I need to use .replace function to replace all the escape sequences with double back slashes when I am reading the regular expressions from file.

Comment: @Zara No. If you are reading from a file, you do not have to escape backslashes. Keep them the way you already have it: `"/^\x3c(REQIMG|RVWCFG)\x3e/ism"`. I believe your question was why no error when reading from the file. Reading from the file seems like the correct way to implement this. The only reason why I think you may want to use literal strings instead is while testing it.

Comment: Okay . The link that I referred in that it is written that the reserved characters used in the (enabled) syntax must be escaped with backslash (\) or double-quotes ("..."). They said that if we consider the RE as a string otherwise it is not required when reading from a file?

Answer (score 2):

`"\x"` is an invalid escape sequence. You have to escape the backslash: `"\\x"`.

The String literal `"\\x"` represents the string containing `\x`. You only have to escape it in the code, but when you read `\x` from a file, there will be no problem.

Assume your file only contains the next line (no leading or trailing whitespace)

`\x`

and you read the contents of the file into a string:

```
String fileContent = readFileContent();
```

now

```
boolean equal = "\\x".equals(fileContent);
```

`equal` will be `true`.